# MYSQL Database Query with Join and Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table called `tblad_clicks` which tracks the no of clicks for a ads on a website. I also have a table called `tblprofiles` that has userdata stored.

I need to query the database to select the distinct `CLIENTID` (the identifier to know whom an ad belongs to). I then also need to select `profileid` where it is greater than 0 and I think thats that for the `tblad_clicks` table. Then I need to join the `profileid` from `tblad_clicks` with the `profileid` from `tblprofiles` to get the `ZONE_ID` and then I need to join that with `tblzones` to get the `zone_name`

Here is a list of the tables and columns:

(1) **tblad_clicks**

- clickid
- clientid
- profileid

(2) **tblprofiles**

- profileid
- zone_id

(3) **tblzones**

- zoneid
- zone_name

There are more columns in these table but I have shared only required column names.

I am not sure if you are getting me but in essence I need to see how many people from each region have clicked on an ad for each client

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? What are the relationships between the tables and columns in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT A.clientid, A.profileid,
       B.zone_ID, C.zone_name
FROM tblad_clicks A
INNER JOIN tblprofiles B ON A.profileid = B.profileid
INNER JOIN tblzones C ON B.zone_id = C.zoneid
WHERE A.profileid > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select c.clientid, c.clickid, z.zoneid, z.zone_name from tblad_clicks as c inner join tblprofiles as p on p.profileid = c.profileid inner join tblzones as z on z.zoneid = p.zone_id group by c.clientid, c.clickid, z.zoneid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.clientid,z.zone_name,COUNT(*)
FROM tblad_clicks a
JOIN tblprofiles p ON p.profileid=a.profileid
JOIN tblzones z ON z.zoneid=p.zone_id
GROUP BY clientid,z.zone_name
HAVING COUNT(*)>0
```